# Android GCM: registering error

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I created my GCM project, I manage to register and receive messages but I still get:

```
[DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent
{ act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[com.redbend.client]
(has extras) }
```

In similar questions I saw that this error was a result of bad registering of the receiver in the manifest which cause the receiver to get an unregistration intent instead of the receive intent. I succeed on receiving the message but still get this error in the logcat. Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the problem was that after handing the intent I didn't put:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

Hope it will save time for others...